# What is the function that describes double sided topologist sine curve?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I frequently encounter the following image

[image]

How do you describe this function and what is the domain of this function? $\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: $\sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$ for $x\neq 0.$ That is the description as a function, anyway. Depending on what example is desired, one may add, as a SET, the vertical line segment from $(0, -1)$ to $(0,1)$ either with or without the endpoints

Comment: It just looks like $\sin 1/x$.

Comment: @MattSamuel Oh for whatever reason I expected $\sin (1/x)$ to be symmetric across the y axis

Comment: @VerySoftCarpet If you want it to symmetrical across the $y$-axis (aka if you want it to be an even function) you can just use $\cos(1/x)$; it's basically the same thing.

Comment: [Graph of $\cos(1/x)$](http://imgur.com/MDprjvY.png)

Comment: The usual meaning of the topologists' sine curve is sin(1/x) for x>0, or for 1>x>0. So the double-sided one ought to be sin(1/x) for non-0 x..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common example of a function which produces this kind of graph is $$f(x)=\sin(1/x).$$ The domain is $\{x\in\mathbb R: x\ne 0\}$.

Comment: Good point. I'll modify my answer.